# i want previous page URL with GET parameters

Tags: php

Currently i using this ,

```
 $page=urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

which gives url without get parameters, but i need the previous page `URL` with `GET` parameters

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will give you PHP_SELF + GET params

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTP_REFERER` that referred the user agent to the current page

```
$page=urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Referrer header.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Please, keep in mind, a user can change the value of headers, so you can't "trust" it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url ="";
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
 $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}

if want to send post get this as encryption the use 
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
$url = urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

if you want to decrypt the url
$url = urldecode($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply used

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

You will get whole URL (with get parameters)